# Gratis encrypted, synched cloud storage

Tags: windows, gratis, android, file-synchronization

I don't like DropBox, it has way too many "confliceted copies", but the final straw came when it somehow managed to overwrite newer code with older, costing me weeks of effort. Plus, it is not encrypted on my device before sending to their server.

I used to use SpiderOak, which is encrypted on my device before sending to their server, so that they cannot access it.

Alas, I lost my password and it is so secure that their support can't help me, so there go my 15gB, which I got from referring friends.

I am looking for something gratis to synch some files of my choosing between my Windows laptop & Android 'phone. Mutatis mutandis, I would prefer the one with most free storage (extra storage through referrals would be a bonus).

Comment: Self hosted? Build on that backup answer, use the very same Nextcloud? Note we suggest software here, not storage ;)

Comment: Nextcloud is definitely looking good. I am waiting for my server provider to conform that I may install it. If so, you have yet another answer :-)

Comment: Ping me then so I write it up. And name me the solver of your problems :D – no, strike the last part, just kidding ;)

Comment: But, you are the solver of so many of my provlems! Hmm, is there a way to search for all questions asked by me & answered by you? ;-)

Comment: Not with the usual search here. But should be possible via the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/queries) ;)